# What would be the best OOP way to create a function only used inside the class

Tags: python, class, oop

I would like to create a function that is only used as a function inside another function in the same class. My main question is, what would be the best OOP way to create this function ? Should I go as far as to use any type of decorator ; @statimethod etc

For info, it will never be used outside the class, it doesn't need any class variable used inside (so self might not be needed if we want to go with @staticmethod)

```
 class Awesomeness(object):
     def method(self, *args):
         self._another_method(...)
         pass

     def _another_method(self, *args):
         pass
```

Comment: The is no such things as private functions or indeed any other kind of attribute in a Python class. Naming with leading underscore is a convention but is merely a hint to the reader

Comment: @Fred thanks Fred. I will change the question. I am not talking about the naming, it was just a way to explain that it will only be used inside the class

Comment: @minattosama, how do you expect to call that function?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it will be called inside the function. Don't really mind how is called if it is OOP constructed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two reasonable solutions for this, each with its own ups and downs:
First - static, private method:

```
class Awesomeness(object):
    def method(self, *args):
        self.__another_method(...)
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def __another_method(*args):
        pass
```

Leading double underscore causes name mangling, so outside of the class this method would have to be accessed with `_Awesomeness__another_method`. You can also use single underscore which just signifies it is supposed to be private, without enforcing anything.

Another solution, which works only if just one of your class methods is gonna be using this function, is to make it an inner class of this method:

```
class Awesomeness(object):
    def method(self, *args):
        def another_method(*args):
            pass
        another_method(...)
        pass
```

Comment: can you really call a @staticmethod like this self.__another_method(...) ? didn't know it was possible

Comment: Yup, works just fine. `self` is not passed as argument in such case.

Comment: The first one works perfectly fine for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: and what would you suggest if I needed to access a variable inside that 'another_method'. A classmethod would be more OOP ? (question scope outside of the post, no worries)

Comment: what variable? class? instance? something else?

Comment: Something declared during the def __init__()

Comment: So instance variable (e.g. `self.name = "John"`)? Because you can certainly declare local variables in `__init__` that will not be available outside of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251108/discussion-between-minattosama-and-matszwecja).

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to use single and double underscore as prefix for function names.

For example

```py
class Foo:
    def _protected_function():
        ...
    
    def __private_function():
        ...
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/10400050) explains it further.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, however the question is not about the naming but more on the construction of the class itself

Comment: Double underscore practically prevents the function to be called from outside the class. This is the pythonic way to do it. There's no other code or syntaxic way unless you want to create some workaround hacks.